This happened when I was trying to open python IDLE in venv: WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled
WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.
I wrote: "python3 -m idlelib.idle",  but terminal does not workso should I do something now, if IDLE started working as I wanted?
3.12 using their site, the venv is setup with the command python3 -m venv path-to-file

Please update your question with some information. Which version of Python and how was it installed (brew, downloaded installer, etc), and the same info for IDLE if installed separately. How is the venv setup?

@AndyGriffiths, 3.12 using their site, the venv is setup with the command python3 -m venv path-to-file

Fine, but please update the question as requested. Comments can be deleted and content lost. Show the process beginning to end as cut & paste from the terminal. We don't know the actual steps you have taken, or can see what you see.

@AndyGriffiths, Okey, however I even do not understand exactly the meaning of this warning

This was fixed in python 3.12.1.
It's basically just a warning for developers: Apple now recommends that apps save their state using NSSecureCoding, to ensure that a bad person can't manipulate saved state data between sessions.

it turns out that this doesn't even concern the security of the system itself, only about the unknown to me saves of this application?

And after I had updated to Sequoia, I got this error: +[IMKClient subclass]: chose IMKClient_Modern

@NikolaiVorobiev Does python work? If so, I'd just ignore the messages.

Python work, but C++ script with memory leak also works, however we do not want to run it, so I just want to be sure

If it is safe or not

Do You know if it is safe?

Yes. It's just log messages for the devs.
